# Trying to use save as from excel to word get error of object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Trying to create a simple replace function in a word document and create a new file with the saved information to keep the template

keep getting the error of "object doesn't support this property or method" when running the saveas function

```
    Public Sub WordFindAndReplace()
Dim ws As Worksheet, msWord As Object

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

With msWord
    .Visible = True
    .Documents.Open "C:\test\PSNS_Letter.docx"
    .Activate

    With .ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting

        .Text = "MM1 Billy Budd"
        .Replacement.Text = ws.Range("C1").Value2

        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 1               'wdFindContinue (WdFindWrap Enumeration)
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

        .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)
    End With
    msWord.SaveAs ("c:\test\test.docx")
    '.Quit SaveChanges:=True
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: `msWord` is the `Application`... you want to call `SaveAs` on the *document*.

Answer (score 1):

Try, please

```
msWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("c:\test\test.docx")
```

or, even better:

```
msWord.Documents("PSNS_Letter.docx").SaveAs ("c:\test\test.docx")
```